# suggest any Asp.net control for adding date of birth by specify day,month & year in each dropdown control

Tags: asp.net, validation, drop-down-menu

Suggest any Asp.net control for adding date of birth by specifying day,month & year in each dropdown control & its validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you have the option to build it for your own.
Please take a look at this demo site.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Not exactly what you want,but you can customize it.

Here's an example how to use it in ASP.net.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Datepickercontrol.aspx

Hope this help you to kickstart :)

Answer (score 4):

There are far too many date picker controls in the marketplace to count.  Most recently, I have been using the [CalendarControl](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) within the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/) from Microsoft and the [jQueryUI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

If I had to pick one to use over the other, it would be the [jQueryUI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) 100% of the time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#myDate").datepicker();
 });
</script>


<div class="myDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a wealth of Calendar controls available with various pricing at the ASP.NET Community web site:  http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=52